# How to control a function using volume keys or power key in react native

Tags: react-native

i want to integrate volume keys in my react native app so that I can control some functions using the volume keys or power key

Answer (score 2):

You can add a volume change listener using this package [react-native-volume](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-volume).

```
onVolumeChange(volume => console.log(volume));
```